# Intuitive Explanation on Converting BNF Grammar to LR(1)

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, intuition, lr-k

Consider the following BNF Grammar G:

```
object-expression   ::=     id | id ( object-expression ) | object-expression . id
                            | object-expression [ object-expression ]
                            | object-expression . id ( object-expression )
```

I am attempting to construct a set of LR(1) items based on G.

**Attempt:**

Let's represent Grammar G as:

```
O -> id
O -> id ( O )
O -> O . id
O -> O [ O ]
O -> O . id ( O )
```

Item Set 1:

```
O' -> • O, $
O -> • id, $
O -> • id ( O ), $
O -> • O . id, $
O -> • O [ O ], $
O -> • O . id ( O ), $
```

**Can someone provide an intuitive explanation in simple language on how to finish obtaining a set of LR(1) items given a BNF Grammar such as G?**

Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Just follow the algorithm. It is really better if you understand the algorithm, but it won't necessarily make it easier to apply it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've seen the algorithm, but I am unable to find a source that gives an example like the one mentioned. For example, I do not know if `id` needs to be in the item set, and if the lookahead needs to be determined for `id`. Any suggestions?

Comment: If a computer can perform the algorithm, then a human should be able to. Make sure you understand the algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Any suggestions on a source for an explanation of the algorithm?

Comment: Any decent textbook.

Comment: You can find a very nice and easy-to-understand (IMHO) explanation of LALR(1) table construction in Dick Grune & Ceriel Jacobs, A Practical Guide to Parsing Techniques, Chapter 9. While I would definitely recommend the second edition of that book, the first edition is available for [free download](https://www.dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/)